# how to retrieve my dates js selection (FROMDATE, TODATE) in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have my code: http: //jsfiddle.net/2x7gkgu9/10/

I could not get my dates (FROMDATE, TODATE) in javascript.

Help

Comment: Can you be more specific? What **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: my problem is how to get with javascript the dateFrom and dateTo from datepicker filter when i want to select the date  !! thanks Ivan :-)

Comment: So you need to extract dates from dateFrom / dateTo or catch click event on inputs or somethign different? Could you describe your goal step by step?

Comment: Effectively, i need to extract dateFrom and dateTo after an event click. my code fiddlejs is : http://jsfiddle.net/moumni/b4az7t8a/. it's not operationnel  but i need to extract my dates in commented line in my code line n° 45 and n° 47 ! any help please !

Comment: But your example doesn't work. Generally you can extract dates by calling chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes(); http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes